# Which Multimeter is correct?

Tags: resistors, measurement, multimeter

I have two Multimeteres that I'm using to measure resistance of a 10 Ohm resistor. Now, when i measure with the first one it's showing 10.2 Ohms while the other is constantly changing values from 9.9 to 10.8 Ohms. Which one is more reliable?

Comment: Probably the more expensive one.

Comment: Reminds me of Segal's law - "A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure."

Comment: The more expensive one is the second one. Shouldn't the resistance be constant?

Comment: Is the resistor reliable?

Comment: How can I know that? Its 3w, 10 Ohms, 5%

Comment: Have you got both of them connected at the same time? That will probably cause this.

Comment: No, one at a time.

Comment: When measuring low resistances like this, if you want to do it really accurately, you need to use a four-wire measurement (typically only available on bench DMMs). Which implies a much more expensive multimeter, to support Marko's comment.

Comment: Use your multimeter to measure the resistance of its own leads by pushing the tips together. This is a lesson in why @uint128_t mention of four-wire "Kelvin" measurement is important for low or precise resistance measurements.

Comment: If you can't get a stable reading, then you either have a poor connection, or the meter is seriously broken. Fix that issue before proceeding.

Comment: Have you any strong RF fields around? RF pickup is a good way to get unstable readings. Some inexpensive meters are not well hardened against  being disturbed. My kitchen scales misbehave when used next to an operating microwave oven, there's obviously just enough leakage to tickle them.

Comment: how long since they were both calibrated?

Comment: Possibly neither of them.

Comment: I do have wireless mouse, and I have no idea when were they calibrated.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one is probably very accurate if they are inexpensive handheld 
multimeters.

Perhaps the battery is low or the probe sockets are loose on the one that is varying.

You can consult the manuals for your meters to know what the accuracy was when the meters were manufactured. A typical accuracy spec on an ohms range for a cheap DMM might be 0.8% + 3 counts, but you might have to short the probes and subtract off the ohms read to get that accuracy on the *lowest* ohms range. For example, if you short the probes and the meter reads 0.3 ohms, then a reading of 10.2 ohms on the display would be more like 9.9 ohms in reality.

Better meters will tend to hold their calibration longer. I have a Fluke handheld that is still within spec on the voltage and ohm ranges after more than 25 years.

Comment: The one which is varying is about $40 (and I changed the battery an hour ago with the new one), while the other fits entirely in my hand.

Comment: @lakistrike, $40 is a very inexpensive meter. You shouldn't expect too much from either of your meters.

Comment: In addition to @ThePhoton 's comment, I have a $85 meter that I can trust fairly well down to 10.0 ohms, and can *use* returned values down to about 5.0 ohms with a proverbial "grain of salt." Anything below that, however, would require using oxygen-protected leads (for more predictable lead resistance), and anything below, say 1.5ohms would, IMO simply *require* a 4-wire micro-ohmmeter to get a reliably accurate reading.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB You can often cob something together to get a 4-wire reading without buying a special instrument. If you can put about 1A through the resistance (and measure it accurately) then a cheap meter with a 199.9mV range will give a resolution of 100\$\mu\Omega\$ (up to 200m\$\Omega\$ of course). At around 20mA you would get a resolution of 5m\$\Omega\$, or about 20x better than the lowest ohms range, and it can be 4-wire so lead resistance doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Its 3w, 10 Ohms, 5%

That means it can range from 9.5 ohms to 10.5 ohms. The meter that has an unstable reading produces an average value of 10.35 ohms and the more stable meter has a reading of 10.2 ohms.

> Which one is more reliable?

A little bit of oxidization might produce an unstable reading that is also a little bit high in value so, based on your numbers, there isn't really any conclusion to make.

Comment: Well, what multimeter would you use from now on (out of these two) for future measurment?

Comment: Nothing to conclude from this data. More data required to make a judgement plus finding out why the reading was wobbling around on one of the meters.